# Xml with python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

The value which is coming to my variable is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">411,00</string>
```

I want to take 411 from there. How can I do this?

Comment: It's not the same. Here the value is not a child object or something. @timgeb

Comment: I do not understand, the other thread got 411 upvote, why this deserve downvote?!

Comment: Me also. People are giving response without reading my question. @Gang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lxml` like this:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("filename.xml")
print tree.xpath('//text()')[0]
```

You can use `StringIO` to pass an xml code:

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

tree = etree.parse(StringIO('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">411,00</string>'))
print tree.xpath('//text()')[0]
```

`parse` methode expects source to be one of the following:

*filename*
*file object or file-like object*
*URL using HTTP or FTP protocol*

Comment: Error: Failed to load external entity. @Zetys

Comment: Please, can you tell me what you have pass to `parse` method.

Comment: As I wrote within my qustion, exactly. @Zetys As string.

Comment: @EnisD. Check my edit.

Comment: Thanks for this. @Zetys